# Optimization for Mysql Configuration, how do I make my mysql run faster?

Tags: mysql

I have mysql version 8.0.x+
My Database Server RAM and CPU:
[image]

[image]

Here is my current configuration:
[image]

I tried to run a select query like this:

SELECT * FROM db.table1
where Company_ID = 79998 and year = 2009;

It took me about 30s, db.table1 contains around 50m records.

How can I speed up mysql database?

my create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
       `ID` bigint PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
       `Company_ID` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
       `year` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
       `Fiscal_period_ID` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
       `Filing_status_ID` double DEFAULT NULL,
       `Accounting_standard_ID` double DEFAULT NULL,
       `Fundamentals_type_ID` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
       `Is_consolidated` double DEFAULT NULL,
       `Latest_period_end` text,
       `Entry_date` text,
       `Update_date` text,
       `Announcement_date` text,
       `Available_date` text,
       `Revision` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
       `Flag` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
       `Update_lock` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
       `U3_ID_FS` double DEFAULT NULL,
       `EQY_FUND_CRNCY` int DEFAULT NULL,
       `ID_BB_COMPANY` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
       `CLEANUP_FLAG` double DEFAULT NULL,
       `ID_BB_UNIQUE` text
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: It's your queries you need to speed up. Please post the table definition as text together with an explain.

Comment: Please post the output of  `show create table table1 `

Comment: @P.Salmon Hi both, please refer to my edited version! Thanks

Comment: @StudyOnly i do not see any Year column in your table

Comment: I don't see any primary keys here too.

Comment: I would reconsider your choice of datatypes if possible- text does not appear to be useful for dates given you will never be able to do a date comparison without the overhead of a data conversion function.,bigint for a 4 digit year is not appropriate and double being an approximate value is almost never useful.

Comment: @P.Salmon Hi P.Salmon, I did what both of you said by changing data types, and now it takes 20s. But 20s is still way too slow, any other advices for this?

Comment: Did you add suggested indexes? In this case it would be appropriate if you added (don't replace) the revised tale definition to the question.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide additional performance improving suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Partial Answer)

The main concern is that the query isn't using any index.

Add the following index on the table

```
alter table table1 
   add index id_year(ID,Year) ,
   add idex year_id(Year,ID);
```

Run explain plan

```
explain SELECT * FROM db.table1 where ID = 79998 and year = 2009;
```

And see which index is used from the one above, and remove the excess one.

Comment: @StudyOnly what did the execution plan after adding the indexes show ? How fast the query was executed ?